# Convert Single row to Multiple rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table that looks like

```
lastName1   FirstName1  Address1    City1   State1  Zip1    lastName2   FirstName2  Address2    City2   State2  Zip2    lastName3   FirstName3  Address3    City3   State3  Zip3
Williams    Greg    123 W Main  NEWCITY MI  48056   Butler  Jos 456 E 7th AVE   OLDCITY MI  48134   BRESNAN TIM 789 N Rd    SAMECITY    MI  45678
George  Adam    321 W MAIN Rd   NEWCITY MI  48056   Thompson    Mark    645 E 7th AVE   OLDCITY MI  48134   Jordan  Hal 987 N Rd    SAMECITY    MI  45678
```

I want to see it like

```
lastName    FirstName   Address City    State   Zip
Williams    Greg    123 W Main  NEWCITY MI  48056
Butler  Jos 456 E 7th AVE   OLDCITY MI  48134
BRESNAN TIM 789 N Rd    SAMECITY    MI  45678
George  Adam    321 W MAIN Rd   NEWCITY MI  48056
Thompson    Mark    645 E 7th AVE   OLDCITY MI  48134
Jordan  Hal 987 N Rd    SAMECITY    MI  45678
```

Using SQL Server 2008

Comment: `UNION ALL` comes to mind.

Comment: I wonder what this table is supposed to contain in the first place. Multiple identities?

Comment: secret service agents and their cover names

Comment: not that luck :), thye are just dummy names & address. 3 persons (name & address) data in row and about a million such rows. All i want is 3 million rows (each row havin only 1 persons data)

Comment: Still i don't understand downvoting it. That is, design is auwful, but it's quite possible not OP is in charge.

Answer (score 2):

Use `union all`:

```
select lastname1 as lastname, firstname1 as firstname, city1 as city, state1 as state, zip1 as zip
from t
where lastname1 is not null
union all
select lastname2 as lastname, firstname2 as firstname, city2 as city, state2 as state, zip2 as zip
where lastname2 is not null
from t
union all
select lastname3 as lastname, firstname3 as firstname, city3 as city, state3 as state, zip3 as zip
from t
where lastname3 is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new table with the correct columns. 
Then use an INSERT statement with a SELECT query using UNION ALL to get the values

```
INSERT INTO NewTableName (lastname, firstname, city, state, zip)

VALUES 

(SELECT lastname1 AS lastname, firstname1 AS firstname, city1 AS city, state1 AS state, zip1 AS zip
FROM OldTableName 
UNION ALL

SELECT lastname2 AS lastname, firstname2 AS firstname, city2 AS city, state2 AS state, zip2 AS zip
FROM OldTableName 
UNION ALL

SELECT lastname3 AS lastname, firstname3 AS firstname, city3 AS city, state3 AS state, zip3 AS zip
FROM OldTableName );
```

Comment: Thanks Rob & Gordon will try, just that table has names & address. 3 persons (name & address) data in every row and about a million such rows. 
All i want is 3 million rows (each row havin only 1 persons data). I want something that doesnt choke my server to run through a 1 million rows

Comment: I think you must remove the `VALUES` keyword in order to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this runs faster

```
select r.lastname, r.firstname, r.city, r.state, r.zip
from t 
cross apply (
select lastname1 as lastname, firstname1 as firstname, city1 as city, state1 as state, zip1 as zip
where lastname1 is not null
union all
select lastname2 as lastname, firstname2 as firstname, city2 as city, state2 as state, zip2 as zip
where lastname2 is not null
union all
select lastname3 as lastname, firstname3 as firstname, city3 as city, state3 as state, zip3 as zip
where lastname3 is not null) r;
```